# Spring Boot 2.0.4 + OAuth2 + JWT - Cannot get Access Token, returns 405 or just gets mapped into localhost:8080/

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to setup oauth with a Spring Boot rest api, but I'm getting a few problems.

When I try to get the Access Token via /auth/token I either get a 405 - Method Not Allowed:

[image: 405]

Or the response from the base url (localhost:8080/) which is a simple json:

[image: localhost:8080]

The first occurs when I don't define a PostMapping in the EntryController, the other occurs if I set it.

I also can see in the logs:

```
2018-09-10 22:03:16.011  INFO 78436 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/oauth/token],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken> org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint.getAccessToken(java.security.Principal,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException

2018-09-10 22:03:16.012  INFO 78436 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/oauth/token],methods=[POST]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken> org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint.postAccessToken(java.security.Principal,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
```

I've tried everything with no success.

This is the code I currently have:

Main:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class Main extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
}
```

WebServerConfiguration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(
                        (request, response, authException) -> response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED)
                )
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
}
```

OAuth2Configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2Configuration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${check-user-scopes}")
    private Boolean checkUserScopes;

    @Value("${security.signing-key}")
    private String signingKey;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Bean
    public OAuth2RequestFactory requestFactory() {
        CustomOauth2RequestFactory requestFactory = new CustomOauth2RequestFactory(clientDetailsService);
        requestFactory.setCheckUserScopes(true);
        return requestFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(jwtAccessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(dataSource).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenEndpointAuthenticationFilter tokenEndpointAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new TokenEndpointAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager, requestFactory());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints
                .tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .tokenEnhancer(jwtAccessTokenConverter())
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        if (checkUserScopes)
            endpoints.requestFactory(requestFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new CustomTokenEnhancer();
        /*converter.setKeyPair(
                new KeyStoreKeyFactory(new ClassPathResource("jwt.jks"), "password".toCharArray()).getKeyPair("jwt"));*/
        converter.setSigningKey(signingKey);
        return converter;
    }

    /*
     * Add custom user principal information to the JWT token
     */
    class CustomTokenEnhancer extends JwtAccessTokenConverter {
        @Override
        public OAuth2AccessToken enhance(OAuth2AccessToken accessToken, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
            User user = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();

            Map<String, Object> info = new LinkedHashMap<>(accessToken.getAdditionalInformation());

            info.put("email", user.getEmail());

            DefaultOAuth2AccessToken customAccessToken = new DefaultOAuth2AccessToken(accessToken);
            customAccessToken.setAdditionalInformation(info);

            return super.enhance(customAccessToken, authentication);
        }
    }

    class CustomOauth2RequestFactory extends DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory {
        @Autowired
        private TokenStore tokenStore;

        public CustomOauth2RequestFactory(ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService) {
            super(clientDetailsService);
        }

        @Override
        public TokenRequest createTokenRequest(Map<String, String> requestParameters,
                                               ClientDetails authenticatedClient) {
            if (requestParameters.get("grant_type").equals("refresh_token")) {
                OAuth2Authentication authentication = tokenStore.readAuthenticationForRefreshToken(
                        tokenStore.readRefreshToken(requestParameters.get("refresh_token")));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                        .setAuthentication(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authentication.getName(), null,
                                userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(authentication.getName()).getAuthorities()));
            }
            return super.createTokenRequest(requestParameters, authenticatedClient);
        }
    }
}
```

ResourceServerConfiguration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().cors().disable().csrf().disable().httpBasic().disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(
                        (request, response, authException) -> response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED))
                .accessDeniedHandler(
                        (request, response, authException) -> response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED));
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.resourceId("mw/client").tokenStore(tokenStore);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

The controller that is triggering the differences is:

```java
@RestController
public class EntryController {

    @RequestMapping/*(method = RequestMethod.GET)*/
    public ResponseEntity<String> entry() {
        final HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("{\"msg\": \"Hello World\"}", httpHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

If set with RequestMapping I get the Hello World json, if set to Get only I get the 405.

Also I forgot to mention that I'm deploying the application to Tomcat through a war file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please show your controller which has these two methods ?

Comment: @kj007 I've updated the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using @RequestMapping then you need to pass both Path and method like below

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/v1/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> entry() {
    final HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    return new ResponseEntity<>("{\"msg\": \"Hello World\"}", httpHeaders, 
    HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

if you want to use directly @PostMapping, @GetMapping etc then just path is required like this

```
@GetMapping(value = "/v1/hello")
public ResponseEntity<String> entry() {
    final HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    return new ResponseEntity<>("{\"msg\": \"Hello World\"}", httpHeaders, 
    HttpStatus.OK);
  }
```

so use accordingly then check as 405 means api signature does not met with any Rest controller apis you have defined.

let me after correct controller you face any issue.

Comment: The first one fixed it!! Jeez, I''ve spent so many hours trying to debug this and it was this simple. Thanks!